# Detect if a parameter passed to command is a mathematical formula

Tags: math-mode, macros, conditionals, parameters

I'm defining a command which displays braced paragraphs and an isomorphism between them, but I want the command to recognize if one of the paragraphs is something purely mathematical and therefore not show the curly braces. Let me elaborate.

My first try was purely paragraph-oriented. I created a command to give shape to the paragraphs (using `varwidth`), add braces to them, and then another command which would link them:

```
\newcommand{\parrafo}[1]{%
    \left\{%
    \begin{varwidth}{0.25\textwidth}%
        \centering%
        \textnormal{#1}%
    \end{varwidth}%
    \right\}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\reticulos}{omm}{%
    \begin{equation*}%
        \parrafomath{#2} \xrightarrow{\sim} \parrafomath{#3}%
        \IfValueT{#1}{\xrightarrow{\sim}\parrafomath{#1}}%
    \end{equation*}%
}
```

[image: The result of the first command]
The challenge then appeared when one of the three paragraphs was a mathematical structure, like a space `\(E\)`, the command would still render the braces, looking like a set of one element.
[image: Example of the braces around math structure]

So, as I didn't find a solution myself or online, I asked ChatGPT, and what could be done was recognise if the string passed to the command started with `$`, because unlike `\( \)` there was just a character to check. The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

% Detect math mode with $
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\detectar}[1]{%
    \expandafter\@detectar#1$\@end$%
}
\def\@detectar#1$#2\@end${%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
        {\@firstoftwo}%
        {\@secondoftwo}%
}
\makeatother

% \parrafo modified to act differently if a formula is passed
\newcommand{\parrafoMath}[1]{%
    \detectar{#1}{%
        \left\{%
        \begin{varwidth}{0.25\textwidth}%
            \centering%
            \textnormal{#1}%
        \end{varwidth}%
        \right\}%
    }{%
        \textnormal{#1}% %to eliminate the problems of nested math mode
    }%
}

% \reticulos updated with \parrafoMath
\NewDocumentCommand{\reticulosMath}{omm}{%
        \begin{equation*}%
            \parrafoMath{#2} \xrightarrow{\sim} \parrafoMath{#3}%
            \IfValueT{#1}{\xrightarrow{\sim}\parrafoMath{#1}}%
        \end{equation*}%
}

\begin{document}

    \reticulosMath{$E$}{text}
    \reticulosMath[$E$]{text}{text}

\end{document}
```

[image: The last command detecting a first $]

This version works right, but only using `$ $`, it doesn't really recognize if the parameter is a formula. As I have come to know, this syntax is discouraged and it would be preferable `\( \)`, but I can't find any source about detecting if something is a formula. I'm aware of the `\ifmmode` command, but I understand this works only if it's used inside the formula.

I am very new to the if/else syntax in LaTeX and I don't know if there is some command that could solve this issue. I know the command works, but I would prefer something well-built, not depending on a character/string recognition useful only when `$ $` is used.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: `$` is supported latex syntax (just `$$` that is not) You could do more involved regexp tests but I would say you should not do this, any such tests are just looking at syntax if the user has defined `\foo` then you would have to execute that to see if it's text. It is a basic theme of tex design commands are unambiguously math or text not some auto detection. `\alpha` is just math,  `\^` is a text accent `\hat` is a math accent (possibly the same character) etc.

Comment: you could for example add a star `s` option at the start and omit the braces if `*` is used

Comment: I would use `\AddToHook{env/...}` with **every** amsmath environment and set a global flag.  Note that equation and equation* (for eaxmple) are separate environments.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't see how that would help even with amsmath environments, let alone inline maths etc. Even in the case of an environment, the flag won't be set before the environment begins, right? You'd just have the problem of determining whether this-bunch-of-code sets the flag at some point or doesn't.

Comment: Since you are using `\NewDocumentCommand`, wouldn't it make more sense to make the argument spec `{mmo}` so that the final example is `...{text}{text}[$E$]` and not `...[$E]{text}{text}`? // Also, I agree with the other comments that trying to do "automatic detection" is not a great design choice. It would work much better if you do it manually. Two options come to mind: (a) introduce an optional argument that specifies the bracing scheme (basically "which of the arguments need to be braced") (b) define an `\unbrace` macro to wrap around arguments that you don't want braced.

Comment: In option (b) you can just do your test on whether the argument starts with `\unbrace` or not. This is more robust then trying to test for (possibly implicit) mathmode.

Comment: I think the concept is -eh - doomed for two reasons. Reason 1: Choosing the typesetting mode (math mode or horizontal mode or vertical mode) should be done by the user. TeX cannot really decide with almost arbitrary user-input, which typesetting mode would be appropriate.

Comment: One of the problems with implementing an algorithm that does the decision is that one needs precise criteria for deciding what to consider to have the property of being "purely mathematical " and what not to consider to have the property of being "purely mathematical". In edge cases this might require analyzing semantics as well, which is something that is not implemented in TeX.

Comment: Reason 2: Actually you'd need to check the result of expanding the argument of `\reticulos` while checking the result of expanding is a crucial matter in TeX: The argument of `\reticulos` could contain things like ``\bgroup\catcode`\Z=3 \scantokens{ZEZ}\egroup`` where checking if after doing expl3's f- or e-expansion the first non-space has category 3 and thus switches to math-mode is ruled out. And with expansion assignments contained in the arg are not carried out. With f-expansion you don't have guarantee that expansion isn't stopped just after obtaining s.th. with unbalanced curly braces.

Comment: "I asked ChatGPT, and what could be done was recognise if the string passed to the command started with `$`, because unlike `\(` `\)` there was just a character to check." Seems ChatGPT doesn't take into account that most things in TeX are done on "macro-level" which in turn is based on tokens, not just characters, while both `$` and `\(` are single tokens but `\(` is not a character token.

Comment: "I'm aware of the `\ifmmode` command, but I understand this works only if it's used inside the formula." Yes. `\ifmmode` forks depending on whether TeX currently already is in some math typesetting mode. It is a reliable means for deciding whether switching to math mode is needed only in situations where not being in math-mode in any case implies the need to switching to math-mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for `$...$` or `\(...\)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\parrafo}{m}
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A (\$|\c{\(}) (.*) (\$|\c{\)}) \Z } { #1 }
   {
    \mbox{#1}
   }
   {
    \left\{
    \begin{varwidth}{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering\normalfont #1
    \end{varwidth}
    \right\}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\reticulos}{mmo}{%
    \begin{equation*}
        \parrafo{#1} \xrightarrow{\sim} \parrafo{#2}%
        \IfValueT{#3}{\xrightarrow{\sim}\parrafo{#3}}%
    \end{equation*}%
}

\begin{document}

\reticulos{$E$}{text}

\reticulos{\(E\)}{This is a \\ paragraph}[$E$]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I can't see any advantage over the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\NewDocumentCommand{\descset}{m}{%
    \left\{%
    \begin{varwidth}{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering\normalfont #1
    \end{varwidth}
    \right\}%
}
\newcommand{\iso}{\xrightarrow{\sim}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
E \iso \descset{text}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
E \iso \descset{This is a \\ paragraph} \iso E 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same, but the flexibility is much greater.